# Firefox bug with arrow keys jquery

Tags: jquery, firefox, keydown, preventdefault

I have issues with Firefox and keydown function.
It will not trigger the function in Firefox but it works in Safari and Chrome. I know preventDefault is the cause of the problem, but I want to block the default scrolling and trigger an other function.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 40)
    {
        movePointer();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Does someone have other sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version is your firefox? I've tested this on FF12:

```
var movePointer = function() {
    console.log('moved');
}

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if( key === 40 )
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        movePointer();

    }
})
```

Works great for me. You might notice i swapped the `preventDefault` and `movePointer` function, so as the modified the conditionals a bit. It does block the scrolling for the keydown, but not the keyup scroll.

Comment: I updated Firefox and add your alterations and it triggers now the function, thank you